# MySQL Query to perform calculation and display data based on 2 different date criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning,

I am trying to combine two queries into one so that the result array can be populated into a single table. Data is pulled from a single table, and math calculations must take place for one of the columns. Here is what I have currently:

```
SELECT 
    laboratory,
    SUM(total_produced_week) AS total_produced_sum, 
    SUM(total_produced_over14) AS total_over14_sum,
    100*(SUM(total_produced_over14)/sum(total_produced_week)) as divided_sum, 
    max(case when metrics_date =maxdate then total_backlog else null end) as total_backlog,
    max(case when metrics_date =maxdate then days_workable else null end) as days_workable,
    max(case when metrics_date =maxdate then workable_backlog else null end) as workable_backlog, 
    max(case when metrics_date =maxdate then deferred_over_30_days else null end) as deferred_over_30_days
FROM 
    test, 
    (
        select max(metrics_date) as maxdate 
        from metrics
    ) as x
WHERE  
    YEAR(metrics_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(metrics_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY 
    laboratory 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Here's the breakdown:

For each laboratory site, I need:

1) Perform a MONTH TO DATE (current month only) sum, division and multiply by 100 for each site to obtain percentage.

2) Display other columns (total_backlog, days_workable, workable_backlog, deferred_over_30_days) for the most recent update date (metrics_date) only.

The above query performs #1 just fine - I get a total_produced_sum, total_over14_sum and divided_sum column with correct math.

The other columns mentioned in #2, however, return NULL. Data is available in the table for the most recently updated date, so the columns should be reporting that data. It seems like I have a problem with the CASE, but I'm not very familiar with the function so it could be incorrect.

I am running MySQL 5.0.45

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!
Chris

P.S. Here are the two original queries that work correctly. These need to be combined so that the full resultset can be output to a table, organized by laboratory.

Query 1:

```
SELECT SUM(total_produced_week) AS total_produced_sum, 
SUM(total_produced_over14) AS total_over14_sum 
FROM test 
WHERE laboratory = 'Site1' 
AND YEAR(metrics_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(metrics_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT laboratory, total_backlog, days_workable, workable_backlog, deferred_over_30_days,
items_over_10_days, open_ncs, total_produced_week, total_produced_over14 
FROM metrics 
WHERE metrics_date = (select MAX(metrics_date) FROM metrics) 
ORDER BY laboratory ASC
```

Comment: `total_backlog, days_workable, workable_backlog` - are these column names?

Comment: Yes, they are column names. Sorry, should have clarified that.

Comment: could you point to natural primary key, i.e. set of columns that will uniquely identify each row?

Comment: Oh man, I feel realllly stupid. I created a copy (test) of my original table (metrics) for testing purposes. While I used the "test" table at the beginning of the query for the math, I used the original table to pull the rest of the data. The metrics_date between the two tables do not match up, however, so of course the query would return NULL for those columns. Long story short: the above query works as expected -- Operator Error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Operator Error.

I created a copy of the original table (named "metrics") to a table named "test". I then modified the metrics_date in the new "test" table to include data from January 2011 (for the month-to-date). While the first part of the query that performs the math was using the "test" table (and working properly), the second half that pulls the most-recently-updated data was using the original "metrics" table, which did not have any rows with a metrics_date this month.

When I changed the query to use "test" for both parts of the query, everything works as expected. And now I feel really dumb.

Thanks anyway, guys!